# Match positions of named capture groups in Perl's regexps

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

In Perl, named capture groups can be used to extract data from a string using a regex:

```
perl -wle '
    use Data::Dumper;
    "abc" =~ / (?<B> (?<A> a ) b ) c /x and print "match!";
    print Dumper(\%+);
'
```

prints

```
match!                                                                                                                            
$VAR1 = {                                                                                                                         
      'B' => 'ab',                                                                                                            
      'A' => 'a'                                                                                                              
    };
```

But how do you get the *position* of the matches A and B in the string `"abc"`? When using *un*named capture groups, one can refer to the regex variables `@-` and `@+`, but this does not work for named groups (*).

(*) With 'does not work' I mean  that I cannot use the name of the capture group to retrieve the position, but only the number of the group (e.g. `$-[1]` for the start position of group A, but not something like `$START_POS{A}`). This redicules the use of named capture groups, and may not even be possible if one does not know the order of the capture groups in advance.

Comment: "**This redicules the use of named capture groups**"... What does that even mean?

Comment: One of the reasons of using named capture groups is to avoid using numbers to refer to them. Writing `$+{header}` and `$+{age}` makes your code readable, while `$+[42]` might be anything. If now I have to use the number of the capture group to retrieve the match position, what remains of this advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one can refer to the regex variables `@-` and `@+`, but this does not work for named groups.

Let's first establish that `@+` and `@-` work as intended:

```
perl -wle '
    use Data::Dumper;
    "abc" =~ / (?<B> (?<A> a ) b ) c /x and print "match!";
    print Dumper(\@+);'
match!
$VAR1 = [
          3,
          2,
          1
        ];
```

and

```
perl -wle '
    use Data::Dumper;
    "abc" =~ / (?<B> (?<A> a ) b ) c /x and print "match!";
    print Dumper(\@-);'
match!
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          0,
          0
        ];
```

Now, since I posted the above, you have expanded on your question by saying

> (*) With 'does not work' I mean that I cannot use the name of the capture group to retrieve the position, but only the number of the group (e.g. `$-[1]` for the start position of group `A`, but not something like `$START_POS{A}`). *This redicules the use of named capture groups, and may not even be possible if one does not know the order of the capture groups in advance.* (emphasis mine)

I don't quite understand what you mean or why you need this, but my repeated queries remained unanswered, so here is the answer to your literal question.

Looking at [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions), we note that currently there is no mechanism to have another hash which allows you to look up match positions by names of capture groups.

> ***`%LAST_PAREN_MATCH`***
>   ***`%+`***
>
> Similar to `@+`, the `%+` hash allows access to the named capture buffers, should they exist, in the last successful match in the currently active dynamic scope.
>
> For example, `$+{foo}` is equivalent to $1 after the following match:
>
> ```
>    'foo' =~ /(?<foo>foo)/;
> ```
>
> The keys of the `%+` hash list only the names of buffers that have captured (and that are thus associated to defined values).
>
> The underlying behaviour of `%+` is provided by the [Tie::Hash::NamedCapture](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::NamedCapture) module.
>   …
>   This variable was added in Perl v5.10.0.
>   This variable is read-only and dynamically-scoped.

It is actually rather straightforward to build such a lookup table following a match, but as I have mentioned before, I am not sure why you need it and it does not seem like the best solution to any problem I have encountered before. It may not be the most suitable solution to *your* problem, so it would be better for you to explain what problem you are actually trying to solve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'abc';

$str =~ / (?<B> (?<A> a) b) c /x;

my %captured_to_pos = map +(substr($str, $-[$_], $+[$_] - $-[$_]) => [$-[$_], $+[$_]]), 0 .. $#+;

print Dumper $captured_to_pos{$+{$_}} for qw( A B );
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          1
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          2
        ];
```

You have to be more careful if different capture groups can match identical strings, but I see no reason to delve into that without sufficient motivating explanation from you.

Comment: Okay, maybe I was a bit unclear with the '`@-` and `@+` does not work' part. I *could* use these arrays to retrieve the position, but this forces me to use numbers again to refer to the capture groups (e.g. `$-[1]` for capture group A), making the use of named capture groups senseless. I would like to write something like `$START_POS{A}`, is that possible

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do that. It sounds like you have already decided on the solution, but it may not be the most appropriate one.  See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I just thought it should be possible, and that it should be a feature in the language, and I have missed it in the documentation. Why would one need this feature? An example: Write a function that is given two strings (`$string1`, `$string2`) of equal length and a quoted regexp (`$re`) containing named capture groups. The function should match `$re` against `$string1`, extract for each capture group the position of the match and then extract the text at that position from `$string2`. Then, construct a hash with keys being the names of the groups, and values being the text from `$string2`.

Comment: Are you assigning homework now, or is this a concrete problem?! See my updated answer. I am done with this.

Comment: What is your problem? You asked me to explain *what* I want to do. In fact, I would like to do exactly what I explained in the example two comments above. To do that, I think I have to know what I asked in the original question. If that's not the case, feel free to provide another solution (or just an idea) to the data extraction function described above.

Comment: You say that "It is actually rather straightforward to build such a lookup table following a match". Could you please elaborate? This is exactly what I would be interested in.

Comment: The problem with your question is you start with an invalid assertion "**`@-` and `@+` don't work for named groups**". Then you update with "This redicules the use of named capture groups" -- whatever that means. Then you come up with some really artificial problem. It sounds like you are trying to extract named columns from a fixed width data file (for which regexes are the worst choice), but more than likely this is a wild goose chase. Read my answer.

Comment: By the way, the formulation "Write a function..." was not meant to be an order to you, I just wanted to describe the task to be done in a concise way. I'm not a native speaker, so please excuse if that formulation seemed inappropriate.

Comment: Nor am I. ... Regardless, consider the following: It sometimes makes sense for vehicles to have skis in place of wheels. Does it then make sense to expect all cars to have skis built-in?

Comment: I don't have fixed width input. In fact, I have a RNA sequence (`$string2`, e.g. `AAAGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCUUUU`),  use a folding algorithm to obtain its secondary structure in dot-bracket notation (something like `(((((((((((((....))))))))))))).`, `$string1`) and then try to identify structural features in that sequence, which I specify as a regular expression. But since almost no one knows what that means, I decided to factor out the programming task and drop the biology. I'm sorry if the problem seemed to artificial to you, but it's an application I need in my problem domain.

Comment: Well, I realize you updated your answer and it is almost what I want. Therefore, and because of your efforts, I accepted it. The drawback is that you have to know the names of the capture group in advance. Yeah, I would like to have a rather abstract solution, because this makes code re-usable and applicable to similar problems without copying functions and changing 3 characters.  And I don't think that this is a waste of time. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: It is also rather straightforward to do that, but you have to take the time to actually state the problem clearly. At some point, some code is constructing those patterns, assigning names to those capture groups. That's where you do the work, not afterwards. My answer had been updated 12 minutes before you asked me to elaborate.